# Уточняющее «уже́» в планах и прогнозах

Tags: выбор-слов, наречия, частица

«Построят мост уже в следующем году, Смотрите новости уже через несколько минут, Ступай уже»...

Когда говорят, что ремонт длится уже год, нам понятен мотив подчёркивания и само слово (оно и стоит рядышком), которое таким образом выделяется. **Уже́** употребляется здесь как усилительная частица и фиксирует событие или его отсутствие как факт минувшего времени.

Вопрос: насколько оправдано подчёркивание или усиление неконкретных слов, характеризующих планы и перспективы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Частица УЖЕ может употребляться при словах и словосочетаниях, которые обозначают какой-либо отрезок времени, количество чего-либо, подчёркивая значительность последнего, или просто для подчёркивания, выделения слова или словосочетания.

На окончательность, завершённость указывает только наречие: Уже ничего сделать было нельзя - наречие(когда?-уже).

Построят мост уже в следующем году,-частица выделяет определение  "в следующем".

Смотрите новости уже через несколько минут-частица выделяет "через несколько минут",это важно.

Ступай уже - подчёркивает важность императива, настойчивой просьбы уйти.

Уже не раз ты меня спасал -    подчёркивается важность спасения, а не того, что это было в прошлом.Вот если бы было: "Ты меня уже спасал"- было бы наречием и утверждало бы, что это БЫЛО в прошлом. Сравните: Ты меня ещё не спас. Ещё- до сих пор - наречие

Comment: «Через несколько минут, это важно». Блок рекламы длится около 2,5 минут. Это знание важнее и точнее сообщения о «нескольких минутах». Несколько. Это — сколько? Ну, если это важно.

Comment: «Ступай уже» могу воспринимать лишь как настойчивую, но нежную просьбу остаться. Спасибо за Ответ.

Comment: Для авторов рекламы важно, чтобы зритель остался на этом канале и посмотрел новости, которые они рекламируют, потому и сообщают: не уходите, интересные новости совсем скоро, уже через несколько минут.Кстати, могли бы быть именно эти факты и не через несколько минут, а, например, в вечерних или вовсе в субботних. новостях. Чего ж здесь странного?

Comment: "Ступай уже" может произнести и сосед, которому поднадоела соседка  своими разговорами, вот он её деликатно и выпроваживает. Может и мама, или жена, или бабушка которые видят, что молодой человек долго собирается(или пытается что-то объяснить и никак не уйдёт из дома) и опаздывает, собирают его вещи и выпроваживают: "Ступай  уже"(Итак всё ясно, нечего объяснять). Ситуации могут быть разными.

Comment: «Новости совсем скоро»... Вот и замечательно, слов уже довольно! Зачем пересаливать, добавляя «уже»: Уже скоро, уже очень скоро? Насколько важны слова неточные и безотносительные типа таких перлов LifeNews, как «несколько попозже»?

Answer (score 2):

"Уже" в подобных случаях выражает *сопоставительный* (по времени) смысл "раньше, чем могло бы", "раньше, чем предполагалось или планировалось", "раньше, чем можно подумать". Контексту будущего времени это не противоречит, в отличие от предположительно "усилительного" смысла, и такие выражения корректны.

Comment: «Раньше, чем могло бы». Если сегодня получено сообщение, то мост, предположительно, смогут соорудить как в январе (3 месяца), так и в конце года (15 месяцев), и разница так велика, что впору сказать: «лишь к концу года». Спасибо за Ответ.